# Detecting the button click to call the update again. It works on the emulator but not on the physical phone

Tags: java, android, events, mobile, widget

I have an app where I scrape a webpage and display its data. Now, I wanted to create a widget with a button that does the same thing: scrape the page and update automatically. I've added the button, and it works on the emulator; it calls the update and the necessary methods again. However, on the physical device, it doesn't work. I've tried creating apps from scratch to detect the clicks and everything, but it still doesn't work on my phone.
Another thing, the toast messages I put for debugging purposes to check don't work, only the logs are called neither in the emulator nor on the physical phone.Could you help me?

AlturaRioWidget.class

```
package com.example.webscraping;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class AlturaRioWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    String url="https://contenidosweb.prefecturanaval.gob.ar/alturas/";
    static String alturaNueva;
    static String variacionNueva;
    static String fechaNueva;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), AlturaRioWidget.class.getName());
            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
            onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }
    }
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            LoadDataRio(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetId);
            Log.i("hola","update");
            RemoteViews remoteV = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.altura_rio_widget);
            Intent intentSync = new Intent(context, AlturaRioWidget.class);
            intentSync.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE); //You need to specify the action for the intent. Right now that intent is doing nothing for there is no action to be broadcasted.
            PendingIntent pendingSync = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intentSync, 0); //You need to specify a proper flag for the intent. Or else the intent will become deleted.
            remoteV.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh,pendingSync);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteV);

            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    public void LoadDataRio(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId){
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    Element valor = doc.getElementsByClass("SANTA FE").first();
                    Element row = doc.select("tr:contains(SANTA FE):not(:contains(San Javier))").first();
                    alturaNueva= row.select("[data-label=Ultimo Registro:]").text(); // 4,00
                    variacionNueva = row.select("[data-label=Variacion]").text(); // -0,05
                    fechaNueva = row.select("[data-label=Fecha Hora:]").text();
                    Log.i("hola","data");
                    latch.countDown();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("Error", e.getMessage() + " "+"ERRORRR");
                }
            }
        }).start();
        try {
            latch.await();
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.altura_rio_widget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.altura_tv, alturaNueva);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.variacion_tv, variacionNueva);
            String replaceFecha = fechaNueva.replace("/24","");
            String replaceFecha2 = replaceFecha.replace("/","-").replace(" ","");
            String fechaEdit = replaceFecha2.substring(0,9)+":"+replaceFecha2.substring(9,11);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.fecha_tv, fechaEdit);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            Log.i("hola","seteos");

        } catch (InterruptedException e ) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            Log.i("Error", e.getMessage() + " "+"ERRORRR");
        }

    }

}
```

altura_rio_widget

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/Widget.Webscraping.AppWidget.Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Webscraping.AppWidgetContainer"
    android:clipToOutline="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Rio Parana(Santa Fe)"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        ></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/altura_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="0.30"
        android:textSize="33dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        ></TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"

        android:paddingLeft="-79dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fsubiendo"></ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="Var:"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="-155dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/variacion_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="-0.30"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="-90dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="Fecha:"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="-10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fecha_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="24-FEB 00:00"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="120dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        ></TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/refreshwidget"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

altura_rio_widget.info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/app_widget_description"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/altura_rio_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/altura_rio_widget"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:maxResizeWidth="300dp"
    android:maxResizeHeight="40dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:previewLayout="@layout/altura_rio_widget"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:targetCellWidth="4"
    android:targetCellHeight="1"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"

    />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_pesca"
        android:label="Altura Rio"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_pesca_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Webscraping"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <receiver
            android:name=".AlturaRioWidget"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/altura_rio_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Loading"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>```


I've tried many tutorials on the internet, followed videos, created an app from scratch, but it seems like the phone doesn't detect, or perhaps I'm missing some code because it works fine on the Android Studio emulator.
````